# Tooltips in a flot-chart

Tags: jquery, charts, tooltip, flot

Can someone please explain this code to me :

```
$("#lineChart").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
             y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
        $("#tooltip").html(x + ', ' + y)
           .css({top: item.pageY, left: item.pageX})
           .fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        $("#tooltip").hide();
    }
```

So I was able to create tooltips for my flot-chart by copy pasting this code and modifying the accompanying css for the #tooltip element. However I cant seem to understand this part of the code specifically what the var item, pos are and what top : item.pageY does?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a heavily commented version of your callback:

```
// you are binding the plot hover event to your graph placeholder div
// the event will fire anytime the mouse is moved within that div
// and you callback function will be called
$("#lineChart").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
    // if the mouse is over a point
    // the callback function will get an item (the point)
    // if the mouse is not over a point it will be null
    if (item) {
        // x, y are the graph coordinates in your x/y axis units
        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
            y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
        // pageY, pageX are the screen coordinates in pixels
        // this will set the tooltip div's html
        // then set the position of the div on the screen
        // then show it
        $("#tooltip").html(x + ', ' + y)
           .css({top: item.pageY, left: item.pageX})
           .fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        // if you aren't over a point
        // item is null, so hide the tooltip
        $("#tooltip").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The x and y variables are numbers based on the 'item' variable passed to the  function. These datapoints are passed to the tooltip with the .html event. I have no idea what the 'pos' is - even though it is passed to the function, in your code it doesn't seem to be used. A wild guess is that it has something to do with the "position" of something, and you haven't given us the full code for the function. The "top" and the "left" are positioning the .html with respect to the tooltip.

Comment: Thanks, what about item.pageY ? This is the full code for the funciton, dont know why the function uses pos. And I suppose item is a point object on the graph?

Comment: The item is probably the image/graph on the page and .pageX and .pageY are probably global variables that define the abscissa and ordinate of the point - note .css 'top' and 'left'. Without seeing more of the code, I'm making guesses.

Comment: The function which configures the tooltip is literally only the part I have shown, there is a part above this function which is just $("#tooltip").css{ //some css to configure div of tooltip};

Comment: Why not use var x and var y values then, why use item.pageY and item.pageX ?

Comment: The x and y variables are the numbers you see in the tooltip. The .pageX and Y probably refer to the position. A way to find out is to comment out the x and y lines, and assign the x and y to "Hello" and "World". Then comment out the .css line and change the top and left parts of the css to fixed variable - watch what happens.